# Prove set equality and function equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

- Problem:

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$ then $A = B \Longleftrightarrow \chi_A = \chi_B$.

- My work:

($\Longleftarrow$) Assume that $\chi_A = \chi_B$, and let $x \in A$. To show that $x \in B$, it suffices to check that $\chi_B(x) = 1$. But $\chi_B(x) = \chi_A(x) = 1$. (Here the first equality follows from the hypothesis $\chi_A = \chi_B$, and the second equality
holds because $x \in A$.) This shows that $A \subseteq B$, and a similar argument shows that $B \subseteq A$.

Therefore, $A = B \Longleftrightarrow \chi_A = \chi_B$. QED

*Is this partial proof acceptable? Can someone suggest a way to prove the other direction?*

Comment: What about the other direction?

Comment: @Loobear23 That's part of my question. Sorry, I forgot to add it in. Can you help?

Comment: Assume that $A=B$. Then consider $\chi_A(x) -\chi_B(x)$ for the cases $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$. Show you get $0$ in either case. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Loobear23, i think i get it. Because we will have 1-1 for $x \in A$ and 0-0 for $x \notin A$. But what about B here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $\chi_A=\chi_B$ (as functions) $A=B$ (as sets). That proof will work to show both inclusions. You van show it at the same time by noting that if $\chi_A=\chi_B$: $$x \in A \iff \chi_A(x)=1 \iff \chi_B(X)=1 \iff x \in B$$

as all implications reverse.

And if $A=B$, $\chi_A=\chi_B$ is likewise trivial: If $x \in A$ then $x \in B$ too and $\chi_A(x)=1=\chi_B(x)$ and otherwise $X \notin A$ so $x \notin B$ and $\chi_B(x)=0=\chi_A(x)$. So $\chi_A=\chi_B$ on the whole domain.